Jetpack Compose - keyboard focus - how to identify an element as the "last in the group"?
We have a composable that includes a few buttons, and this composable is used in a lot of places.  I want to specify the order of focus within our composable, but I want to say that one of them is "the last one"... Here is a simplified example:
Header composable has 3 buttons, which appear top-to-bottom like this:
FIRST
THIRD
SECOND
...and we want the keyboard focus to start on the top one, then go to the bottom one, then the middle.  This is easy using the steps from https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/compose/touch-input/focus/change-focus-traversal-order
However, when someone uses our "Header" composable like this:
HEADER
ANOTHER BUTTON
SOMETHING ELSE
...when you tab on the keyboard, the order is FIRST, SECOND, THIRD, and then because it's the next element down the screen, SECOND again and then THIRD in a loop.
So, the question is: I can specify for FIRST that "next" is SECOND, and for SECOND that "next" is THIRD, but how can I say that for THIRD, the "next" is "jump out of the group and go to the next thing on the screen"?
@Composable
fun WholeScreen() {
    Column {
        TopArea()
        TextButton(
            onClick = { /*TODO*/ },
        ) {
            Text(text = "Bottom Button")
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun TopArea() {
    val (first, second, third) = remember { FocusRequester.createRefs() }
    Column() {
        TextButton(
            onClick = { /*TODO*/ },
            modifier = Modifier
                .focusRequester(first)
                .focusProperties { next = second }
        ) {
            Text(text = "Top First")
        }
        TextButton(
            onClick = { /*TODO*/ },
            modifier = Modifier
                .focusRequester(third)
                .focusProperties {
                    previous = second
                    // next = ????
                }
        ) {
            Text(text = "Top Third")
        }
        TextButton(
            onClick = { /*TODO*/ },
            modifier = Modifier
                .focusRequester(second)
                .focusProperties {
                    previous = first
                    next = third
                }
        ) {
            Text(text = "Top Second")
        }
    }
}


If you run this example, you will see a screen with 4 buttons like:
Top First
Top Third
Top Second
Bottom Button
I want the order here to be Top First, Top Second, Top Third, Bottom Button, but there is no option I can put on "Top Third" to make this happen.  Please help!

Similar question related to keyboard focus: when the user is focused on something "before" this Header group and they enter the group, how can I specify that a specific element should be the first one focused?
